# Log into IIS logs from Owin-based Webapi

Tags: c#, iis, logging, asp.net-web-api, owin

We are trying to get IIS logging working on an Owin-based webapi but so far no luck! In a traditional web app we used to call `Response.AppendToLog("message")` and the message would go to IIS logs. From there we have a tool to collect IIS logs and run some analysis on them. I searched over the internet but I couldn't find anything helpful. If someone has already done this, I appreciate if the would share how to tackle this.

Comment: OWIN attempts to abstract the web server away from you, so it will be surprising if you can use IIS specific API.

Comment: I know it doesn't support it out of the box. I was wondering if there is a nuget or something that will do it.